# Dynamic div id for directive html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, amcharts

I have a problem using dynamic div id in directive template to rendering graph. The error that I get is

> Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

My template.html

```
<div id="{{title}}" style="height: 40vh;"></div>
```

The directive is simply rendering graph on given div id

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        let chart = AmCharts.makeChart(scope.title, {
          type: "stock",
          theme: "light",
          dataSets: [scope.data.dataset],
          panels: [{
            showCategoryAxis: false,
            recalculateToPercents: "never",
            title: scope.data.title,
            valueAxes: [{
              title:  scope.data.type,
              titleFontSize: 10,
              titleBold: false
            }],
            stockGraphs: [{
              id: "g1",
              valueField: "value",
              comparable: true,
              bullet: "round",
              bulletBorderColor: "#FFFFFF",
              bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
              balloonText: "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
              compareGraphBalloonText: "[[title]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
              compareGraphBullet: "round",
              compareGraphBulletBorderColor: "#FFFFFF",
              compareGraphBulletBorderAlpha: 1
            }],
            stockLegend: {
              periodValueTextRegular: "[[value.close]]"
            },
          }],
          panelsSettings: {
            mouseWheelZoomEnabled: true,
            marginLeft: 60
          },
          valueAxesSettings: {
            axisAlpha: 1,
            gridThickness: 0,
            axisThickness: 1,
            inside: false
          },
          categoryAxesSettings: {
            minPeriod: "ss"
          },
          chartScrollbarSettings: {
            graph: "g1",
            usePeriod: "10mm",
            updateOnReleaseOnly: false
          },
          chartCursorSettings: {
            cursorPosition: "mouse"
          },
          periodSelector: {
            dateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS",
            periods: [{
              period: "hh",
              count: 1,
              label: "1 hour"
            }, {
              period: "hh",
              count: 2,
              label: "2 hours"
            }, {
              period: "hh",
              count: 5,
              label: "5 hour"
            }, {
              period: "hh",
              count: 12,
              label: "12 hours"
            }, {
              period: "MAX",
              label: "MAX"
            }]
          }
        });

      }
```

Anybody have an idea how to get around this problem, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ID on the div by using `ng-attr-`. For example: `<div ng-attr-id="title" style="height: 40vh;"></div>`

Comment: I have try this before and got the same error, seems like the function got execute before the template is rendered.